# How do I make my dataframe fit when receiving the error "ValueError: X has 18 features, but LogisticRegression is expecting 105 features as input."

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logistic-regression, predict

I am working on a large data set (57052 rows and 109 columns). The data has been filtered down to the correct columns. We have to find correlation of customer churn and a number of variables. I created a correlation matrix and sorted the dataframe by coefficients in descending order. From there I created a logistic regression model and produced more coefficients and the intercept. I then ran the summary using the sm.Logit function and produced a summary table.

Now here is where the error occurs... I tried using the model.predict function to create a set of predictions. The error returned is "

```
ValueError: X has 18 features, but LogisticRegression is expecting 105 features as input."
```

I first tried to use other dataframes to match the columns to see if they would run and they didnt. It is because the new dataframes are specific to the data I need. Next I tried merging dataframes to get the appropriate amount of columns and was unsuccessful.

I have been researching on how to add a number of "dummy" columns to fill that requirement with 0 values... I am unsure if this would work or if I am over thinking it.

```
##shape of x_coor1 object
```

(57052,18)

The goal of this is to create a confusion matrix based on those variables.

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Problem solved by performing a training and test data split.